# Interested to find a good resource with all active bitcoins exchanges

Tags: exchanges

I am looking for recommendations for good bitcoin exchanges resource that would include info on:
- live/approximate daily trading volumes
- spreads 
- and most importantly traded currencies

I found this one: https://bitcoincharts.com/markets/
But it is not up to date (no KRW for example) and I couldn't find a way to sort it by an exchange and it is a bit hard to compare traded volumes by exchange because the info is in different currencies.

Thanks,
Tagir

Answer (score 1):

Cryptonator looks like a good start. 
Find all exchanges for a particular trading pair. 
https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/eth-btc

Then swap out the `eth` with whatever currency you're looking for.

Cryptonator says this is all their supported currency pairs (https://www.cryptonator.com/api/currencies) but looks like it includes some dead coins. You could loop through that URL and for each record, input the symbol into the original `https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/eth-btc` end-point.

`https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/ltc-btc`
`https://api.cryptonator.com/api/full/dash-btc`
...and so on.

Once the loop is through you should have all pairs and all currencies, or at least all the ones cryptonator has.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not everyone can easily work though the JSON file from the cryptonator api. It will take me quite some time to actually get any meaningful data from there. May be there are some resources that already did the crunching? Also to clarify the questions, I am looking for BTC to FIAT pairs linked to a USD. For example https://www.okcoin.cn/marketList.do. Not looking for alt coins rates.